# When do Eigenvalues of $Q^TAQ$ and $A$ coincide?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Lets say I have some $n\times n$ matrix  $A$ and a $n\times l$ matrix $Q$, whose columns for a basis for some subspace $\mathcal{L} \subset \mathbb{R^n}$. My intuition tells me that I would need $Q$ to be a full orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$ (*i.e.* $l=n$), such that all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of  $Q^TAQ$ and $A$ coincide.

However, I don't see where in the proof for the latter assertion the same dimensionality is needed:

- Be $v\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ an eigenvector of A, i.e. $Av=\lambda v$. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Q^TAQ$ with eigenvector $Q^Tv$:
  $$
  (Q^TAQ)(Q^Tv)=Q'A(QQ^T)v=Q^TAv=\lambda(Q^Tv).
  $$
- Be $v\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}$ an eigenvector of (Q^TAQ), i.e. $(Q^TAQ)v=\lambda v$. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $Qv$:
  $$
  A(Qv)=IAQv=QQ^TAQv=Q(Q^TAQv)=\lambda(Qv).
  $$

Maybe you can help me out here. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: $QQ^\top \neq I$

Comment: [Orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) are always square. Therefore this question does not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, you are indeed right Marc. I read a math paper, where they introduce the above mentioned matrix Q as "orthogonal" (which is also why I assumed $QQ^T=I$) but as you point out their definition is not quite correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case Q forms an *orthonormal* basis of $\mathcal{L}$, you have $Q^TQ = I$, but as long as $l<n$, $QQ^T \neq I$.  Notably, $QQ^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by the columns of $Q$.

Comment: I think we would need the additional assumption that the columns of Q form an orthonormal(!) basis to get $Q^TQ=I$, right?

Comment: Right, I misread the question earlier